# How to convert a structure array's field to .txt file

Tags: matlab

I have a structure array `model_dlib` with these fields:

```
model_dlib.refU
model_dlib.outA
model_dlib.ref_XY
model_dlib.render_width
model_dlib.render_height
model_dlib.sizeU
model_dlib.indbad
model_dlib.threedee
```

I need to convert the `model_dlib.refU` field (320×320×3 double) to a `.txt` file. How do I do this?

Stuff I've tried (that didn't work):

```
fid = fopen('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\refU.txt', 'w');
fprintf (fid, '%s \f', model_dlib(1).refU{:,:,1});
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the 3 different "layers"? Place them below each other?

Comment: No I just want to extract the refU field from the array into .txt. I just copied this code from some website. New to matlab here

Comment: Is `model_dlib(1).refU` a cell or matrix? Do you want the txt-file comma separated? What do you get if you type `class(model_dlib(1).refU`? Do you get an error when you type `model_dlib(1).refU{:,:,1}`? I'm guessing you get "`Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.`"?

Comment: On typing class(model_dlib(1).refU) output is: ans =

double. Yes I want the txt file comma separated

Comment: Do you want it comma-separated? Space-separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
array_3d = model_dlib(1).refU;    %% A 320x320x3 matrix
array_2d = array_3d(:,:,1);       %% Extract the first layer
array_1d = array_2d(:).';         %% Make it a horizontal vector

%% Comma separated:
csvwrite('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\refU.txt',array_1d)
```

This gives you a single line, comma separated file:

```
0.56175,0.20139,0.25511,0.6222,0.37601,0.35895,0.028651,0.76737,0.23738,0.56175
```

---

If you are a one-liner enthusiast (but please don't do this, you'll get a major headache later on):

```
csvwrite('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\refU.txt',reshape(model_dlib(1).refU(:,:,1),[],1))
```

<s>Updated question:</s>

```
%% Space separated:
save('C:\Users\cortana\Desktop\refU.txt','array_1d','-ascii')
```

The first approach gives:

```
0.56175,0.6222,0.028651
0.20139,0.37601,0.76737
0.25511,0.35895,0.2373
```

Note that the line breaks are not displayed in Notepad. However, if you try to open it in Notepad++, MATLAB, MS Word, MS Excel ..., the line breaks will be there.

The second approach gives:

```
   5.6174979e-01   6.2220070e-01   2.8650626e-02
   2.0138985e-01   3.7601341e-01   7.6737463e-01
   2.5510711e-01   3.5895197e-01   2.3738395e-01
```

Comment: That gives me extracted data. But the data I am getting is divided into separate lines. I need data in this format: https://github.com/shaoguangcheng/faceFrontalization/blob/master/3DModel/refU.txt, because I need to put it into this project.